Linear functionals on infinite dimensional Banach space
Suppose $X$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space. Let $\phi,\psi\in X^*$ such that there exists $X\ni x\neq 0$, $\phi(x)=1$ and $\psi(x)\neq 0$. Is it always true that $\psi=\psi(x)\phi$, i.e., the linear functional $\psi$ is a multiple of $\phi$? My thoughts, it suffice to show for any $y\in X$, $\psi(y)=\psi(x)\phi(y)$. Let's start with decomposing $y=\phi(y)x+y-\phi(y)x=\psi(y)x+y-\psi(y)x$. Then
$$\psi(y)=\psi(\phi(y)x)+\psi(y-\phi(y)x)$$
If the second term vanishes, we are done. I am stuck here. Maybe this is not true. Is there any counterexample?

No. Let $X$ be a Hilbert space, $h$ be a unit vector and $k$ be another unit vector which is not orthogonal to $h$ but not a multiple of $h$ either (which exists as long as $\mathrm{dim}(X) \geq 2$). Then let $\phi = \langle h, \cdot \rangle$, $\psi = \langle k, \cdot \rangle$, and $x = h$.

For $\dim X\ge 2$ there exist linear functionals $\varphi,$ $\psi$ ,   which are linearly independent. Then $\ker\varphi\not\subset\ker\psi$ and $\ker\psi\not\subset\ker\varphi.$ Hence there are $x_1,x_2$ such that $\varphi(x_1)=0,$ $\psi(x_1)\neq 0$ and $\psi(x_2)=0$ and $\varphi(x_2)\neq 0.$ Then for $x=x_1+x_2$ we get $\varphi(x)\ne 0$ and $\psi(x)\neq 0.$ We can rescale $x$ to get $\varphi(x)=1$ and $\psi(x)\neq 0.$
